# Unix: How to update an attribute value in XML files via CLI?

Tags: xml, shell

I'm trying to replace one line from an XML file but not able to. I want to replace this line:

```
<dp:request domain="@DOMAIN@">
```

With this one:

```
<dp:request domain="export">
```

But I’m not able to. I have tried below variations of sed commands:

1. ```
   sed -i -e "s/<dp:request domain="export">/<dp:request domain="@DOMAIN@">/g" file.xml
   ```
2. ```
   sed -i s#<dp:request domain="export">#<dp:request domain="@DOMAIN@">#g file.xml
   ```

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/schemas/management" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
  <env:Body>
    <dp:request domain="@DOMAIN@">
      <dp:set-config>
        <ConfigDeploymentPolicy name="@DEPLOYMENTPOLICYNAME@">
          <ModifiedConfig>
            <Match>*/*/crypto/cert?Name=HHMM&amp;Property=Filename</Match>
            <Type>change</Type>
            <Property/>
            <Value>@HHMM.crypto.cert.FileName@</Value>
          </ModifiedConfig>
        </ConfigDeploymentPolicy>
      </dp:set-config>
    </dp:request>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Comment: Show us input file. sed is not meant for parsing xml. Better use xmlstarlet

Comment: Hi @GillesQuénot I have attached xml file first part

Comment: Please, read [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @GillesQuénot my bad I have uploaded complete xml file

Comment: @ShubhamGurao you cannot, must not parse any structured text like XML with tools designed to process raw text lines. If you need to process XML, use an XML parser. A great majority of languages have built-in support for parsing XML and there are dedicated tools like XMLStarlet if you need a quick shot from a command line shell. Never accept a job if you don't have access to proper tools.

Comment: Très bien expliqué, je me permet de le copier pour les prochaines interventions, merci Léa

Answer (score 2):

##### With [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet) and a [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) query:

```
$ xmlstarlet edit -N dp="http://www.datapower.com/schemas/management" \
     -u '//dp:request/@domain' -v export file.xml
```

##### Output

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/schemas/management" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
  <env:Body>
    <dp:request domain="export">
      <dp:set-config>
        <ConfigDeploymentPolicy name="@DEPLOYMENTPOLICYNAME@">
          <ModifiedConfig>
            <Match>*/*/crypto/cert?Name=CC_OMS_QA3&amp;Property=Filename</Match>
            <Type>change</Type>
            <Property/>
            <Value>@CC_OMS_QA3.crypto.cert.FileName@</Value>
          </ModifiedConfig>
        </ConfigDeploymentPolicy>
      </dp:set-config>
    </dp:request>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/), the special purpose language to transform XML files, which carry many [CLI processors](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt/info) (i.e., Saxon, Xalan). Below uses `xsltproc` available on Unix machines. You can extend the XSLT to do *many* other transformations and still call the single command line!

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl file, a special .xml file)*

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- IDENTITY TRANSFORM TO COPY DOC AS IS -->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
    
  <!-- ADJUST ALL domain ATTRIBUTES -->
  <xsl:template match="@domain">
     <xsl:attribute name="domain">export</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

<kbd>[**Online Demo**](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPgAEdP)</kbd>

**CLI**

```bash
xsltproc myScript.xsl Input.xml > Output.xml
```